# Why for loop update statement cant be updated inside the loop

Tags: java, for-loop, counter

I am trying to update the for loop variable `i` inside the loop, why I cannot update it and the i is always 0?

```java
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; ){
            i = i ++;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
     }
}
```

I am expecting print out

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

but it is a infinite loop and print out all 0.

Comment: what is the return value of `i++`? it is the value before doing the increment; so `i` is being incremented and then the old value reassigned (you could have done `i = i + 1 ` - assign the value added 1 - would work perfectly, or just `i++`, no assignment, what most programmers do, inside the `for`)

Answer (score 3):

You can, but with `i = i ++;` you're not incrementing the counter. Use `i++` instead - it's an operator that does not return a new value, only increments the primitive.

Keep in mind, that `for` loop is meant to contain the information about looping. If you manipulate the counter outside of loop, you might loose track of what is going on. This is not recommended, better use `while` in that place.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @roundAbout why?

Comment: @Eran sure, that's why it compiled - I meant "the new one", forgot to write it. Thank you.

Comment: thanks, i tried i = ++i; it works. and if i = i ++; the i++ would be executed eventually and why it cant be updated?

Comment: @rickyfok what you did is `. assign `i` to `i`, and then increment, but the incremented value is never used. with `i = ++i` you're first incrementing the value, then assigning the new one to variable `i`.

Comment: understood, thanks for your help.